# Under what conditions on a, b, c in R is the following set A linearly dependent?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

These are 2x2 matrices. I have the answer to the question above but Im not exactly sure how that answer was gotten, if someone could explain it, it would be quite helpful. Thanks in advance.

$$A=\left\{
  \begin{bmatrix}
  a & b \\
  0 & c
  \end{bmatrix},
  \begin{bmatrix}
  1 & 2 \\
  0 & 3
  \end{bmatrix}
\right\}$$

Answer: $A$ is linearly dependant iff

$$
  \begin{bmatrix}
  a & b \\
  0 & c
  \end{bmatrix}=scalar\cdot
  \begin{bmatrix}
  1 & 2 \\
  0 & 3
  \end{bmatrix}
$$

for some scalar in $\Bbb R$. iff $b = 2a$ and $c = 3a$

Comment: Please don't delete and repost your question, especially without addressing any of the concerns indicated in the comments you received: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1205116

Comment: thanks........ @ZevChonoles

Comment: Hey @Rory do you have any idea why that format wont display correctly for me? Partly the reason I didn't originally post using correct syntax.

Comment: I can't say, but for me, when my post gets "too long" it stops updating the format on my screen. I now plan to do my posts at [MathB.in](http://mathb.in/) for practice, and copy my final answer over to here. I haven't started doing that yet.

Answer (score 1):

Which part is unclear?

By definition, $A$ is linearly dependent, iff
$$ \mu 
  \begin{bmatrix}
  a & b \\
  0 & c
  \end{bmatrix}
+ \tau
  \begin{bmatrix}
  1 & 2 \\
  0 & 3
  \end{bmatrix}
=0$$
For $\mu,\tau \in \mathbb R$ not both $0$. If $\mu$ where $0$, $\tau$ would have to be zero as well (e.g. by the top left component $\mu \cdot a=\tau$), so $\mu \neq 0$ and we can divide by $\mu$. Substituting $\lambda = -\tau/\mu$, this is equivalent to

$$
  \begin{bmatrix}
  a & b \\
  0 & c
  \end{bmatrix}
= \lambda
  \begin{bmatrix}
  1 & 2 \\
  0 & 3
  \end{bmatrix}$$ 
for some $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$. In components:
$$ a = \lambda \cdot 1, \quad b=\lambda \cdot 2 \quad\text{and} \quad c =\lambda \cdot 3$$
Substituting the first equation $\lambda = a$ in the latter two gives
$$ b= 2a \quad\text{and} \quad c =3a$$
($a=\lambda$ can be dropped, as $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ is arbitrary.)